# How to manually download an MMS without opening?

Tags: android, incident-response, stagefright

I'm looking into a potential Stagefright attack on an Android mobile (AOS 5.+). But since I'm not an expert on the subject, I fail to find a simple way to safely download the MMS for inspection. I was hoping to find a way to setup (the APN) proxy and download the MMS via an external browser or using `curl` or `wget`. But I can't find any such solutions.

**What Linux tools are available for this?**

(Ideally I'd like to use some shell CLI tool to do this, directly from within the phone, or using `adb`)

I've posted a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117466/is-there-a-way-to-download-an-mms-from-command-line-using-curl-or-wget) but so far no response. I find it strange that such a widespread and popular hack doesn't have any analysis tools to deal with it.